# First Transaction Date and Amount and Latest Transaction Date and Amount

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I created a table called 'donation'.
This table has

```
supporter_KEY ( member unique identifier)
first_name,
last_name,
donation_key (transaction unique identifier)
email 
amount and date
```

Here is some data

```
supporter_KEY   first_name  last_name   email               donation_key    (date)        (amount)
37519405        ALEX        LANGER      alex@email.com      12447199        2011-04-14    10:38:00.000  100
37519483        Anthony     Russo       anthony@smail3.com  12464169        2012-07-30    14:12:00.000  125
37519656        Bert        Kaplan      sample1@aol.com     12460672        2011-11-25    08:08:00.000  35
37519905        Brett       Graham      sample2@yahoo.com   12466260        2013-01-14    10:43:00.000  100
37519939        Bruce       Decker      sample3@hotmail.com 12466441        2013-03-20    08:59:00.000  25
37520331        Craig       Pettigrew   sample4@aol.com     12464780        2012-08-28    13:52:00.000  25
37520787        Donn        Schaible    sample9@aol.com     12466886        2013-04-09    16:50:00.000  125
37521145        George      Cooper      sample43@gmail.com  12420119        2011-03-09    10:17:00.000  100
37521145        George      Cooper      sample43@gmail.com  12459908        2011-07-19    09:19:00.000  50
```

I am trying in one query to pull the latest transaction amount and date and in the other query to pull the first transaction date and amount

Here is each query:
Query for first transaction date and amount:

```
SELECT supporter_KEY,
   first_name,
   last_name,
   email,
   donation_key,
   MIN(date) as first_transaction_date,
   MIN(Amount) as first_transaction_amount
FROM donation
WHERE supporter_KEY > '1'
GROUP BY supporter_KEY,first_name,last_name,email,donation_key
```

And the Query for the latest transaction date and amount:

```
SELECT supporter_KEY  ,
   first_name ,
   last_name,
   email,
   donation_key ,
   MAX(date) as latest_transaction_date,
   MAX(Amount) as latest_transaction_amount
WHERE  supporter_KEY > '1'
FROM donation
GROUP BY supporter_KEY,first_name,last_name,email,donation_key
```

I just want to make sure I am on the right track and I would also like to pull the largest `Trx` Date & Amount (?).

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries are essentially the same.  Here's the query for the first transaction, to get the latest transaction change the `MIN` in the subquery to `MAX`.  Note that this will only select the first row (with unknown sorting) if there is more than one row with the same `date`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    supporter_KEY, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    email, 
    donation_key, 
    date as first_transaction_date, 
    amount as first_transaction_amount
FROM 
    donation 
WHERE 
    date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM donation)
```

Comment: Hi, would you get the first and the last for each member? or how could I do this?